# Delphi drag and drop panels in container

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop

How can I catch the onDargDrop event when using this approach:

```
procedure TMain.layerRowMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  ReleaseCapture;
  (Sender as TPanel).Perform(wm_nclbuttondown,HTCAPTION,0);
// and now in order to preserve the nice alignment of panels...
  for i := 0 to Main.ComponentCount - 1 do
    begin
      if Main.Components[i] is TWinControl then
        if TWinControl(Main.Components[i]) is TPanel then
        if (TWinControl(Main.Components[i]) as TPanel).Parent=Main.ScrollBox1 then
          begin
            (TWinControl(Main.Components[i]) as TPanel).Align:=alTop;
          end;
    end;
  end;
```

I mean, the drag/drop works but being an OnMouseDown event... this fires everytime I click on the panel. I want to be able to differentiate between clicking and dragging.

More specifically, I have a panel, inside it I have a scrollbox (alClient).
Then at runtime, onButtonClick I create panels containing some stuff, and I align them alTop. So my panels align themselves to top, bellow the older ones just like in this picture:

[image]

So, I add panel1, it adds itself to the top, then I add panel2 it adds itself bellow panel1, and so on (just like in the picture).

Now, I want to be able to move panels around (change their order), so I use the above code that I attach to each panel to it's onMouseDown event.

So it works ok, but I need to know when an actual drag/drop occurs because I need to be doing some code after the drag/drop happens, and I cannot have that code execute everytime a mouse click happens.

So what do you suggest?
This approach is nice, because looks simple and also shows the panel while dragging. So I need a similar solution or a way to differentiate in the onMouseDown: when it's just click and when it is drag/drop

Thank you

Comment: Looks simple ... and does not work. You need a threshold to test when the mouse is moved if left button is still pressed. Can't do that in mouse down. If you ever get this working, you'll have find out how dragging works in VCL.

Comment: I actually soved my problem using other approach... like... I hold the order of the panels in a virtual table, and onMouseDown I check to see if the order in the table differs from the order in the container... then it means I must have moved a panel. It's not pretty, but it works. I leave the question open though just in case someone finds a prettier solution